# Missing timezones. Can't set several cities

Tags: timezone

I want to add several cities to the time menu that appears when you click the clock in the menu bar.

Auckland (New Zealand) and Port Lewis (Mauritius) are not in the list of available cities. I have successfully added Frankfurt, Moscow, Denver so everything else is working just some cities are missing.

Why are some timezones missing? Many Pacific & African capital cities that I have tried are not on the list.

Is there another package to add these?

If so why is it not loaded by default?

I'm using 16.04. Home timezone is UK/London. 
Had same problem in previous version but can't remember how to fix it. Why not load all cities on install or first update?